# LuaForWindows, update Lua

Tags: lua

I'm using the latest LuaForWindows v5.1.5-52 that comes with Lua 5.1.4, but I want to use the latest version of Lua (5.4) because I'm reading the "Programming in Lua 4th edition" and it is recommended to use the latest version.

Is there a chance to "update" or "change" Lua without breaking its library dependences ?

If not, do you recommend to install lua binaries + libraries instead of LuaForWindows ? I've not done that yet, because I cannot find a step-by-step guide about how to do that (specially the 'libraries' part; Anybody knows where I can find some detailed guide ?)

LuaForWindows comes with all the stuff, so it's very easy to start, but that's different if you want to install lua binaries + libraries, as I don't know how to install them and which ones are necessary.

Thanks

Comment: I started writing a [step-by-step guide](https://github.com/LuaScripters/tutorial/blob/master/windows.md) for installing Lua on windows from scratch a while ago, but it's still quite unpolished :D

Comment: Back in the day I used Windows I simply used precompiled lua binaries, put them in a directory and make sure that directory was part of PATH. After that I made sure that directories with libraries were included in LUA_PATH or LUA_CPATH environment variables. Last time I did that it worked just fine.

Comment: That being said migrating from 5.1 to anything newer is almost a guarantee that something will break.

Comment: Ook, thanks for your advice... I'll try it asap !

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work: What I've done so far is:

-    copied the contents from lua libraries (dlls and .a files) in lua-5.4.0_Win32_dllw6_lib.zip to C:\lua5.4\clibs

- included in LUA_CPATH C:\lua5.4\clibs\?.dll AND C:\lua5.4\clibs\?54.dll

    rebooted windows

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is NO.

LuaForWindows is simply a distribution with Lua and several modules built for that Lua version.

What you want requires a full new version of LuaForWindows, with the new Lua version and new version of all the modules it has, built for that new Lua version. The problem is that not all that modules have being built for other Lua versions than 5.1.

Also LuaForWindows is not updated in 4 years. The recommended replacement is LuaRocks, but not all that modules are available in LuaRocks, some has to be manually installed.